# Combining AND/OR statements in one python line

Tags: syntax

I am writing some code in python now I run into a problem with the following IF statement:

`if Row1==['X', 'X', 'X'] or Row2==['X', 'X', 'X'] or Row3==['X', 'X', 'X'] or ((Row1[0] and Row2[0] and   Row3[0])=='X') or ((Row1[1] and Row2[1] and Row3[1])=='X'):`

the first 3 statements seem to work well. But the fort one ((Row1[0] and Row2[0] and Row3[0])=='X') messes things up. meaning, the "and" and " or" logic does not perform as stated.

So I guess I do something wrong with the syntax.

Any thoughts appreciated

I tried variations in the syntax like adding () a , or a ;  They all did not work. What works is if I seperate each statement in a seperate elif; so:

`if Row1==['X', 'X', 'X'] or Row2==['X', 'X', 'X'] or Row3==['X', 'X', 'X']: print("Speler 1 XXX heeft gewonnen") elif ((Row1[0] and Row2[0] and Row3[0])=='X'): print("Speler 1 XXX heeft gewonnen TEST")`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `(Row1[0] and Row2[0] and Row3[0])`?  Are you trying to do a logical AND on those values?  Are they booleans? Or, at the least, nulls?

Comment: If you are trying to say "if all 3 row values have the same first value and it's equal to 'X'", your syntax is definitely off.